# I am trying to think which is the best way for a simple crud

Tags: wpf, forms

Having little experience I am wondering which is the best way to add a simple CRUD functionality for the ListView there.The design is incomplete.The two black buttons down there are for Create end Edit .
Opening a new form for editing / adding ,i think is a really bad idea.
Adding dynamically a textbox and a label between the buttons and the listview seems a little odd ,i think that it can be confusing.Like pressing New then what if user changes tab or presses edit? Also for editing what if user changes selection from list ? It is a bit confusing... Another option is to hide listview when editing or adding a new.... But nothing satisfies me.
The other solution is datagrid but seems a little weird not friendly for simple users.
Any other solution/suggestion ?Thank you for your time!
[image: ds]

**UPDATE**
The left menu has Personnel,Catalog,Tables,Settings...

Right the three textboxes are for 3 tax rates. At bottom at the listview are some  cancellation reasons,they are predefined strings. User can add /edit/delete  them. They will be used later from other forms so user wont have to type why the order was cancelled.
I moved the buttons at right and look better - easier to use

Comment: Without knowing Greek, it's hard to answer because we don't know the context of the controls, or the data around them. Do you have a translated version to hand? I do think it will increase response rate.

Comment: Unfortunatelly i dont have a translated version. I care for the bottom listview. They are some predefined texts ,for cancellation reasons. User should add his reason. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the UI becomes confusing is the user can select a different item in the list once another item is in edit mode.  If using a modal dialogue for editing/adding an item is not an option, I would suggest using a datagrid where the selected item expands to allow editing.

[image]

However, if you are looking for a quick user friendly solution, I think popping up a modal dialogue is still a good choice.  All users understand the concept and it forces the user to focus on the item he/she is adding/editing at that stage.

Comment: i will try popup or to hide the listview while editing. Maybe i didnt make my point clear.The top 3 textboxes are not related with the reasons!